# how to check which fragment is visible

Tags: android

I have 3 fragments that can be replaced in a particular layout. I have a button in the main activity. I want the text color of the button to change accoring to what fragment is currently displayed on the screen. is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Your Toast should be

```
Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```